Reading data from SQLite file using multiple threads - Column wise read vs Row wise read
I have a SQLite database file with one table with following schema
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    blob1 BLOB,
    blob2 BLOB,
    blob3 BLOB,
    blob4 BLOB,
    blob5 BLOB,
    blob6 BLOB
);

Each of the BLOB columns will be between 3 and 4 MB of size.
I also have 300 rows in the file (corresponding to ~ 7 GB of total dataset size)
I need to optimize loading of this entire data to memory, so I am trying out parallel reads of the data.
I am performing the following 2 approaches

Parallel column reads - Create 6 threads and each thread reads data from all rows in a single column (for example thread 1 reads select blob1 from my_table, and so on.)
Parallel row reads - Create 6 threads and each thread reads all column data for a given range of rows (for example thread 1 reads select blob1, blob2, blob3, blob4, blob5, blob6 from my_table where id >= 1 and id <= 50)

I am using SSD for disk storage. And the database page size is 4 KB.
Since the blob size is way more than the database page size, I was not expecting a big difference in the performance of both approaches, however it turns out that the first approach of parallel column reads completes within 4.2 seconds whereas the second approach takes 6.6 seconds (this is more than a 30% performance improvement in parallel column reads)
FWIW, the baseline data of select all columns from all rows also takes ~6.6 seconds.
Are there any plausible explanations for why this improvement in column wise reads?
